# How can I exit a function without ending the whole program? (Python)

Tags: python, function

I'm trying to make a reroll function on a game I'm making, but it won't accept no for an answer when it asks "do you want to roll again?". The loop continues as if I answered yes. I'm using a counter of types to control how many times you can reroll, so I tried setting the counter to above the allowed amount, but that doesn't work. The counter does work to allow rerolls until it surpasses the allowed amount, so that doesn't seem to be the problem.

```
for i in range(6):
  #rolls 6 faces of a die and sets them to a "hand"
if counter == 0:
  print("1",hand1,"\n","\nYou earned",resolve1,"resolve")
else:
  print("\n1",hand1,"\n","\nYou earned",resolve1,"resolve")
counter = counter + 1
if counter < 3:
  yn = input("\nDo you want to roll again? (Y/n)\n")
  if yn == "y" or "Y":
    hand1 = []
    resolve1 = 0
  elif yn == "n" or "N":
    counter = 4
else:
  print("\nYou cannot reroll\n")
  counter = 4
```

I'm pretty much a novice btw, just did computer science at GCSE a few years ago.

Comment: `return` .......

Comment: where is your function definition?

Comment: You do not have a function and indentation is not needed in many places.

Comment: This is just an except from my function and when I tried return the problem persisted.

Comment: An excerpt needs to be complete enough to run without changes to see the same problem, and similar enough that the same solutions apply. If `break` "doesn't work" in your real code, we need your example to be complete enough it won't work in the example either, and such that someone can actually see that with their own eyes _only_ using code included in the question itself. See the [mre] definition; being as short as possible is the "minimal" part, but it needs to do that while still satisfying the "reproducible" part.

Answer (score 1):

I hope my version of the code works. Some of your indentations were wrong, and for the if...or... statements, you need to tell the code what is equal to what every single time you use the or statement if yk what I mean.

So for instance:

```
if yn == "y" or "Y"
```

won't work, so you will have to write:

```
if yn == "y" or yn == "Y"
```

Here is the edited code:

```
for i in range(6):
  #rolls 6 faces of a die and sets them to a "hand"
    if counter == 0:
        print("1",hand1,"\n","\nYou earned",resolve1,"resolve")
    else:
        print("\n1",hand1,"\n","\nYou earned",resolve1,"resolve")
        counter = counter + 1
    if counter < 3:
        yn = input("\nDo you want to roll again? (Y/n)\n")
    if yn == "y" or yn == "Y":
        hand1 = []
        resolve1 = 0
    elif yn == "n" or yn == "N":
        counter = 4
    else:
        print("\nYou cannot reroll\n")
        counter = 4
```

Comment: Hi there! Try to focus on well-asked questions. This question was asked over a year ago, was unclear, and had some formatting problems. See also the "how to answer" guide: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: Thanks for giving me that advice, but I'm not a good programmer, so I try to look for easy questions to improve my skills. But anyways, thanks for your advice.

Answer (score 0):

Try returning a value or using the [break keyword](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwi35snE9pTzAhUJqxoKHUfVB84QFnoECB0QAw&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.tutorialspoint.com%2Fpython%2Fpython_loop_control.htm&usg=AOvVaw2-kAi2SqPrZB5F33yGojTs).

Comment: `break` cannot end a function it can end a loop, although the `return` can

Comment: Something must be wrong elsewhere because break isn't stopping it...

Comment: Yes. but if the loop is broken the function will end since it seems that it only consists of the loop. @BigChungo